# Optimize MySQL query because it gets time out

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, phpmyadmin

Can anyone help me with optimizing this query. I can not execute it because phpMyAdmin connection gets timed out and i have no access to change time out parameter.

Here is a query:

```
INSERT INTO `goods` (`goods_id`, `price`, `name`)
SELECT `sales_goods`.`goods_id`, `sales_goods`.`price`, `sales_goods`.`goods_id`
FROM `sales_goods`
WHERE `sales_goods`.`sales_goods_id`
IN (
    SELECT MAX(`sales_goods`.`sales_goods_id`)
    FROM `sales_goods`
    WHERE `sales_goods`.`sales_goods_id`
    IN (
        SELECT `sales_goods`.`sales_goods_id` FROM `sales_goods` 
        WHERE `sales_goods`.`goods_id` NOT IN (SELECT `goods`.`goods_id` FROM `goods`)
    )
    GROUP BY `sales_goods`.`goods_id`
)
```

Comment: Avoid IN clause it is performance killer... I mean try to change query to JOINS instead of nested INs

Comment: Even after translating the query from lithuanian, it's a bit hard to make sense of what you're trying to do...

Comment: I agree, I cannot make sense of it - I thought I knew.. but this MAX?!? @user2319233 try to explain your goal

Comment: Try removing the second inner query its of no use... Hope it helps..

Comment: I've deleted duplicate "goods" names from "goods". But those ids are in "sales_goods" table and I'm trying to restore entries in "goods" table which i have deleted

Comment: please provide your table structure with some data and your expected output.... we'll give you the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from ensuring your tables are propery indexed you can replace your `IN` subqueries with `INNER JOIN`, and your `NOT IN` subqueries WITH `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL`, this should improve the performance:

```
INSERT INTO `goods` (`goods_id`, `price`, `name`)
SELECT  `sales_goods`.`goods_id`, 
        `sales_goods`.`price`, 
        `sales_goods`.`goods_id`
FROM    `sales_goods`
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  MAX(`sales_goods`.`sales_goods_id`)
            FROM    `sales_goods`
                    LEFT JOIN `goods`
                        ON `goods`.`goods_id` = `sales_goods`.`goods_id`
            WHERE   `goods`.`goods_id` IS NULL
            GROUP BY `sales_goods`.`goods_id`
        ) MaxSalesGoods
            ON MaxSalesGoods.sales_goods_id = `sales_goods`.`sales_goods_id`
```